# Who designed/created DDR?

Tags: dance-dance-revolution

I've only ever seen Dance Dance Revolution (DDR) credited to "Konami." Does anyone know which invdividuals were responsible for designing/directing the game?

Comment: I apologize if videogame history questions are off topic for this site... from looking at the FAQ I assumed they would be okay--but perhaps not?

Comment: I can only think that the downvotes are for lack of research effort, but it's not like the answer is right there on Wikipedia - I just looked myself. I will never understand the downvote standards here on Arqade. I personally have upvoted you because this seems like a fair enough question.

Comment: I did not vote either way, but I imagine the people who did downvote are voting it off-topic due to it kind of falling under a question about game design/development.

Comment: @KyleRone I hope that's not the case, because that's not what downvotes are for. Downvotes are not close votes and vice versa.

Comment: @F1Krazy sorry, thats not exactly what I meant. I didnt mean they were voting them as close votes but just because it is off-topic. I would hope those people flagged it if thats why they downvoted, but ya never know.

Comment: @F1Krazy Pretty much anything that goes through the new user "First Posts" queue gets down voted and if there's any excuse at all to justify it, it'll get close votes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://remywiki.com/DanceDanceRevolution_credits

While the English wikipedia page doesn't seem to list credits for the game, pages in other languages may (example:  [Spanish Wiki Page](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_Dance_Revolution_(1ra_edici%C3%B3n)) ). While I can't seem to confirm the full list as a single list elsewhere, [RemyWiki](https://remywiki.com/DanceDanceRevolution_credits) does match to the wikipedia list on the elements where they overlap (thus supporting its accuracy), but offers a wider range of credits.

Cross-referencing the individual names does provide further sources confirming their involvement with the projects (example:  [DDR designer Kanako Yonezawa on MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,71823/)), in the same roles listed by the remywiki page (though it should be noted that the secondary sources I found did not necessarily confirm association with the first game itself), so the list does seem to be correct.

In regards to answering the specific question you presented, Yoshihiko Ota was the producer in charge of the project,  Katsunori Okita and Kazuya Takahashi were the directors, and the following were designers on the project: Nobuo Tomita, Eiichi Yoshioka, Yukiko Mizoo, Yutaka Sakaue, Mitsuo Nagamoto, Tomohiro Ota, Kazushi Hasegawa, Takashi Inubushi, Akira Iizumi, Yoshiko Oiwa, Kanako Yonezawa.

If you're looking for general development background, [The Ringer](https://www.theringer.com/2018/11/15/18096364/dance-dance-revolution-20-years-later-1998-video-games) has a decent article on how the first DDR came about.

Comment: Bless you for this awesome answer. :)